# Setting metaClass property on domain object

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Any reason not to use metaClass on domain objects? as in

domainObjectInstance.metaClass.dynamicTransientGreeting = "Hello"

Will this mess with hibernate at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't mess with Hibernate at all since it won't be seen by Hibernate. GORM only maps "real" properties to Hibernate properties.

That's why the `id` and `version` columns and the collections that are generated from `hasMany` declarations (e.g. the `users` collection generated by `static hasMany = [users: User]` are added to the actual bytecode using an AST. If they were added just to the MetaClass they wouldn't be seen and wouldn't be persistent.

Comment: Thanks Burt for explaining in detail, as always!